# How can I get rid of this bulge?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

This bulge on the glove has appeared whilst I was adjusting my hand and arm armature. I figured it was just down to messing with the Weight Paints, but after trying, I could only reduce it slightly. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: A blend is good, but ideally blend files should be supplemental to good question content, e.g. a detailed description of your problem and screenshots to illustrate your points. We ideally want people to be able to answer the question (or see if they have the same problem) as easily as possible.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Okay, I’ll be sure to make the problem more clear in future. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: The Bulge in Question...]

You should have added that picture; I'll bet a hundred would know in a second. It's the inside of the glove poking the wrong way. It's weight is too strong and possibly to the wrong bone. It's outpacing the outside of the glove (assuming it's a glove specifically) and moving faster than the positive-facing normals. That gray strange color is the dead giveaway; those normals are flipped and display like that when you haven't enabled 2-sided. (I'm glad you didn't enable 2-sided or it wouldn't show up so clearly.)

Less weight will reduce your swelling. That will keep the gap between outside and inside from inverting. Depending on your needs, you might paint that portion to another bone? I understand the problem but can't tell you the perfect solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’ll look into it today. I did try and reduce the weight yesterday, but the swelling only reduced so much. I’ll make sure it’s to the right bone as well and check the normals.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not able to fix it. The glove has weights in the D_hand.R and D_forearm.R groups, but applying a weight of 1 (red) only reduces the issue somewhat, but doesn't clear it completely.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you have both your FK and IK showing at once? I'm trying to clear the pose and recreate the problem but then think, how about Clear Transform: All, piece by piece? Finger Poles. I reverted to the file you sent me and cleared ONLY the blue, like: H_finger_5_ik.R and when all cleared, the bulge is totally gone.

Comment: I don't quite follow. With a FK, does that have to be set as a Constraint like IK? I don't see it on the list. Or I take it that by default, without IK applied, it uses FK automatically...?
Thing is, using Clear Transform or resetting the blue IK poles resets my pose, either completely or the clenched fist.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm on the verge of fixing it. :) I cleared the transforms for the blue IKs and I'm re-positioning them more carefully and tweaking the weights whenever the bulge starts to form.